# Why 'mvn install' war projects?

Tags: maven, build, maven-war-plugin, maven-install-plugin, maven-dependency

My `maven` project packages a `war`, which only gets deployed and is itself not a dependency to other projects (in other words is a final deployable).

**Questions**:

- is there any reason to ever run `mvn install` on that package, which, in addition to `mvn package` only puts it in the `localRepository`?
- Why should a final deployable be installed if nothing ever depends on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a final deployable artifact indeed there may be no reason to invoke the `install` phase instead of the `package` phase: you want to build the `.war` file and you don't need to install it in your local repository indeed.

However, you may want as an habit to always run integration tests, if any. Looking at the [default Maven lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) these phases happen **after** the packaging:

> `package` take the compiled code and package it in its distributable format, such as a JAR.
>   `pre-integration-test`  perform actions required before integration tests are executed. This may involve things such as setting up the required environment.
>   `integration-test`  process and deploy the package if necessary into an environment where integration tests can be run.
>   `post-integration-test` perform actions required after integration tests have been executed. This may including cleaning up the environment.
>   `verify`    run any checks to verify the package is valid and meets quality criteria.
>   `install`   install the package into the local repository, for use as a dependency in other projects locally.

Hence, by invoking `install` you would make sure to always execute integration tests as well. Indeed a shorter invocation would be

```
mvn clean verify
```

Less popular but more effective in these cases.